# Recover docker container's run arguments

Tags: docker

I often find myself in need of re-creating container with minor modifications to arguments used to `docker run` container originally (things like changing published ports, network, memory amount).

Now I am making images and running them in place of old containers.

This works fine but I don't always have original params to `docker run` saved and sometimes (esp. when there are lot of things to define) it becomes pain to recover them.

Is there any way to recover `docker run` arguments from existing container?

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for being a couple of years late, but I had a similar question and no satisfying answer yet, so I still needed to find my way out.

I've found two sources addressing the issue:

- A [gist](https://gist.github.com/efrecon/8ce9c75d518b6eb863f667442d7bc67)

> To run, save this to a file, e.g. `run.tpl` and do `docker inspect --format "$(<run.tpl)" name_or_id_of_running_container`

- A [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nexdrew/rekcod)

> Quick run:
> `$ docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock nexdrew/rekcod <container>`

Both solutions are quite simple to use, but the second one failed to generate the command for an Nginx container because they did not manage to have it quoted like this `"nginx" "-g" "daemon off;"`

So, I focused on the first solution, which is a golang template intended to feed the `--format` parameter of `docker inspect`. I liked it because it was kind of simple, elegant, and no other tool needed.

I've made some improvements in [my forked gist](https://gist.github.com/ictus4u/e28b47dc826644412629093d5c9185be) and notified the original author about it.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of answers to this. Run your containers using `docker-compose`, then you can just run compose files and retain all your configuration. Obviously compose is designed for multi-container applications, but massively underrated for single-container, complex `run` argument use cases.

Second one is to put your `run` command into a `LABEL` on the image. Take a look at [Label Schema](http://label-schema.org/rc1/)'s `docker.cmd` etc... Then you can easily retrieve from the image (or from your Dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is not to type the commands manually. put them into a shell script... a `.sh` file on linux/mac, or a `.cmd` file on windows. then you just run the shell script to create your container and you never have to worry about re-typing the commands and options, you'll never get them wrong, etc.

personally, i write my scripts with "npm scripts" in my package.json file. but the same thing can be done with any tool that can run command-line program with arguments

i do this along with a few other tricks to [make sure i never fail to build my images or run my containers](https://sub.watchmecode.net/debugging-docker-images/). makes life with docker soooo much easier. :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this won't really fit my case. Shell script is good when you are working on some project and you know you'll need to create your container in the future. I often don't know that beforehand. I use docker (among other things) to tinker with new things, so I create\throw away containers often and I need only a small (unknown) portion of them for reuse some time later. Managing shell scripts is just too much burden\overkill in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker inspect` to get the container's configuration. Reconstructing the `docker run` command from that can be somewhat tedious though.

Another option is to search your shell history using either `history | grep "docker run"` or `ctrl+r` (if you use `bash`). That way, you don't need to go out of your way to save the commands but can still recover them quickly.